# Generating ROP-chains containing arbitrary strings

Tags: security, assembly, x86-64, exploit

I already built some ROP-Chains to get a shell.
But I my new task is to build a ROP-Chain that executes an elf file using *execve*.

So I wrote this piece of code, compiled it and it works just fine.
But in a ROP-Chain I need to push those strings on the stack, which I assume I can't because I can not find anything usefull in my gadget list.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
   char *const parmList[] = {"foo", "bar", "alpha", NULL};
   char *const envParms[2] = {"MYENVVAR=HELLO", NULL};
   execve("./myProgrammIwantToExploit", parmList, envParms);
}
```

For ROP gadgets I used my /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.24.so

Comment: Pushing something on the stack doesn't quite make sense from within a ROP chain; after all, with each gadget you execute, the stack pointer is advanced.  Why do you think you need to push something on the stack?

Comment: Normally you inject your ROP chain to the stack so you can embed any data, assuming it is known ahead of time. Otherwise you will need to find some gadgets which might not be `push` but simple indirect memory writes. Also note that 64 bit sysv uses registers to pass arguments. Of course you still need your strings somewhere in memory.